# How do I mock an Angular service using jasmine?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

This may be a duplicate but I have looked at a lot of other questions here and they usually miss what I am looking for in some way. They mostly talk about a service they created themselves. That I can do and have done. I am trying to override what angular is injecting with my mock. I thought it would be the same but for some reason when I step through the code it is always the angular $cookieStore and not my mock.

I have very limited experience with jasmine and angularjs. I come from a C# background. I usually write unit tests moq (mocking framework for C#). I am use to seeing something like this

```
[TestClass]
public PageControllerTests
{
    private Mock<ICookieStore> mockCookieStore;
    private PageController controller;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockCookieStore = new Mock<ICookieStore>();
        controller = new PageController(mockCookieStore.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetsCarsFromCookieStore()
    {
        // Arrange
        mockCookieStore.Setup(cs => cs.Get("cars"))
                    .Return(0);

        // Act
        controller.SomeMethod();

        // Assert
        mockCookieStore.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

I want mock the $cookieStore service which I use in one of my controllers.

```
app.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', function($scope, $cookieStore) {

    $scope.cars = $cookieStore.get('cars');

    if($scope.cars == 0) {
            // Do other logic here
            .
    }

    $scope.foo = function() {
        .
        .
    }
}]);
```

I want to make sure that the $cookieStore.get method is invoked with a 'garage' argument. I also want to be able to control what it gives back. I want it to give back 0 and then my controller must do some other logic.

Here is my test.

```
describe('Controller: PageController', function () {

    var controller,
        scope,
        cookieStoreSpy;

    beforeEach(function () {
        cookieStoreSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('CookieStore', ['get']);
        cookieStoreSpy.get.andReturn(function(key) {
            switch (key) {
                case 'cars':
                    return 0;
                case 'bikes':
                    return 1;
                case 'garage':
                    return { cars: 0, bikes: 1 };
            }
        });

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$cookieStore', cookieStoreSpy);
        });
        module('App');

    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller;
    }));

    it('Gets car from cookie', function () {
        controller('PageController', { $scope: scope });
        expect(cookieStoreSpy.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cars');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution for the discussion we had in my previous answer.

In my controller I'm using $location.path and $location.search. So to overwrite the $location with my mock I did:

```
locationMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('location', ['path', 'search']);
locationMock.location = "";

locationMock.path.andCallFake(function(path) {
  console.log("### Using location set");
  if (typeof path != "undefined") {
    console.log("### Setting location: " + path);
    this.location = path;
  }

  return this.location;
});

locationMock.search.andCallFake(function(query) {
  console.log("### Using location search mock");
  if (typeof query != "undefined") {
    console.log("### Setting search location: " + JSON.stringify(query));
    this.location = JSON.stringify(query);
  }

  return this.location;
});

module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('$location', locationMock);
});
```

I didn't have to inject anything in the $controller. It just worked. Look at the logs:

> LOG: '### Using location set'
>
> LOG: '### Setting location: /test'
>
> LOG: '### Using location search mock'
>
> LOG: '### Setting search location: {"limit":"50","q":"ani","tags":[1,2],"category_id":5}'

Comment: +1 Thanks for the effort. and location is the next one I needed :) Let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the arguments, spy on the method

```
// declare the cookieStoreMock globally
var cookieStoreMock;

beforeEach(function() {
  cookieStoreMock = {};

  cookieStoreMock.get = jasmine.createSpy("cookieStore.get() spy").andCallFake(function(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'cars':
        return 0;
      case 'bikes':
        return 1;
      case 'garage':
        return {
          cars: 0,
          bikes: 1
        };
    }
  });

  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('cookieStore', cookieStoreMock);
  });
});
```

And then to test the argument do

```
expect(searchServiceMock.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cars');
```

Comment: Have I not done this. Please look at my test. I am sure I am doing that. Also I asked about how to inject my mock not how to create one.

Comment: But you're injecting it with $provide.value('$cookieStore', cookieStoreSpy), while it should be $provide.value('cookieStore', cookieStoreSpy);

Comment: even if it is an angular service? I thought I had to reference it with the dollar.

Comment: I tried to change and it made no difference. $provide.value('$cookieStore, cookieStoreSpy)' or $provide.('cookieStore', cookieStoreSpy) both don't work.

Comment: Also change cookieStoreSpy.get.andReturn to cookieStoreSpy.get.andCallFake

Comment: I got it working. All I had to do was change the call to the controller to controller('PageController', {$scope: scope, $cookieStore: cookieStoreSpy}). It seems when angular creates the controller it will first try get it from your array of dependencies before trying its own providers. HOWEVER, my question remains, how do I change what angularjs would provide for $cookieStore by default?

Comment: First of all you where right - it should be $provide.value('$cookieStore', cookieStoreSpy) fince in your controller you also inject it with $. 

I'm wondering why it is working without controller('PageController', {$scope: scope, $cookieStore: cookieStoreSpy} - you should get the cannot find $cookieStoreProvider exception.

Comment: Perhaps it happens because of:
"To prevent accidental name collision, Angular prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $. Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally collide with Angular code." (from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace)

Comment: And I was right - there is a $cookieStore factory inside angular-cookies.js line 133.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use that $cookieStore (the angularjs $cookieStore) in my controller. And I want to mock it out in my test and use my own version of it.

Comment: Than I think $cookieStore: cookieStoreSpy is the solution.

Comment: but it isn't. Because when I use the debugger I can see it is still the Angularjs $cookieStore and not my jasmine spy. And that brings me back to the question that I posted. How do I mock an Angular service using jasmine? Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I posted a new answer, since the code was to long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example https://github.com/lucassus/angular-seed/blob/81d820d06e1d00d3bae34b456c0655baa79e51f2/test/unit/controllers/products/index_ctrl_spec.coffee#L3 it's coffeescript code with mocha + sinon.js but the idea is the same.

Basically with the following code snippet you could load a module and substitute its services:

```
beforeEach(module("myModule", function($provide) {
  var stub = xxx; //... create a stub here
  $provide.value("myService", stub);
}));
```

Later in the spec you could inject this stubbed service and do assertions:

```
it("does something magical", inject(function(myService) {
  subject.foo();
  expect(myService).toHaveBeenCalledWith("bar");
}));
```

More details and tips about mocking and testing you could find in this excellent blog post: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/09/advanced-testing-and-debugging-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

Why mock cookieStore when you may use it directly without modification? The code below is a partial unit test for a controller which uses $cookieStore to put and get cookies. If your controller has a method known as "setACookie" that uses $cookieStore.put('cookieName', cookieValue) ... then the test should be able to read the value that was set.

```
describe('My controller', function() {
   var $cookieStore;
   describe('MySpecificController', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $controller, _$cookieStore_) {
        $cookieStore = _$cookieStore_;
        // [...] unrelated to cookieStore
    }));

    it('should be able to reference cookies now', function () {
       scope.setACookie();
       expect($cookieStore.get('myCookieName')).toBe('setToSomething');
    });

 });
```